# Is possible rewrite row in workbook from array without use for loop (all row values)?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

If I have a array eg `arrData()` I can do `ws.rng = arrData`.
Is there any construction to do this just for the row?
My idea: `ws.Range(ws.Cells(Row,0), 1), ws.Cells(Row, 1).Offset(0, Col)) = arrData(Row,*?*)`

Why not use for? I using for loop go through the Row in `arrData(Row,Col)`. `arrData` contains ONLY changed values and two more columns that determine where they belong (file xx, row yy). Another excel can also write to the file xx.

The **point is make** the **write operation as fast as possible**. Alternatively, prevent it from being recorded at the same time (when it is opened in another Excel). The second Excel writes several values to the xx file several times a day at an unknown time.

I was still thinking of `open` xx **read-only**> load into `arrTmp` > `close` xx > change values in `arrTmp` > `open` xx **read-write** > insert change `arrTmp` > `close` and `save` xx
This would keep the storage time to a minimum...

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next way, please:

```
Sub testArrayDataSliceRow()
   Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet, arrData(), arrRow, r As Long
   
   Set ws = ActiveSheet 'use the necessary sheet
   Set ws1 = ws.Next    'use the necessary sheet
   arrData = ws.Range("B3:E10").value
   r = 3                     'the row to be used
   arrRow = Application.Index(arrData, r, 0) 'extract 1D array of the r row
   Debug.Print Join(arrRow, "|")             'just to visually check what it returns
   'Place the row slice in the same row of the next sheet:
   ws1.Range("A" & r).Resize(1, UBound(arrRow)).value = arrRow
End Sub
```

Comment: @excel222 Didn't the above example code clarify your question?

Comment: I tried the code, it's good as an answer to the main question.

Comment: @excel222 Not care to much about checking it as accepted answer... I would like to know if you understood the array slicing method. It is good to know that it is also possible to slice a column or a specific number of rows/columns, even if it needs a code a little more complex.

Answer (score -1):

I remember doing something similar, but it was a while ago.

The key to speed is to remember to chuck your data writes as much as possible.
To do this create an array with only 1 row and as many columns as you need something like:

```
redim arrRow(1 to 1, 1 to numCol) 'size it
arrRow(1,1) = arrTmp(row_i, 1) 'add/ manipulate your data
```

Then your write would look something like:

```
ws.Range(ws.Cells(yy, 1), ws.Cells(y, 1).resize(1, numCol) = arrRow
```